# Как можно редактировать в одной таблице несколько записей?

Tags: php, база-данных

Здравствуйте! Как можно редактировать в одной таблице несколько записей в БД? Например, есть таблица `Gallery`, в ней `id`, `jpg_url` и  `title`. Допустим, пользователь открыл все картинки из этой таблицы и захотел изменить названии несколько картинок. Как тогда поступить: методом `POST` отправлять все `id` в массивах и там извлечь эти массивы, создать функцию "`UPDATE` до тех пор, пока массив < 0" или как еще делать? Кода нет, пока только думаю.

Подскажите!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть одно хитрое решение. Для начала, можно в POST-запросе передавать массив, где ключиком будет id записи и значением новое название для изображения.

```
// Прилетевший массив
$img_vals = array('5' => 'Фото5','10' => 'Фото10','112' => 'Фото112');

// Формируем запрос
$query = "INSERT INTO `mytable` (`id`, `photo_name`) VALUES ";
foreach($img_vals as $key => $val){
    $query .= "('$key','$val'),";
}
$query = substr($query,0,-1);
$query .= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `photo_name` = VALUES (`photo_name`)";

// Если вывести готовый запрос (echo $query;), то увидим примерно следующее:
INSERT INTO `mytable` (`id`, `photo_name`) VALUES ('5','Фото5'),('10','Фото10'),('112','Фото112') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `photo_name` = VALUES (`photo_name`)

// Остается запустит его
$res = mysql_query($query);
```